# Google Maps Marker As a Link

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I've been trying to get this to work for hours :-(

It's actually a posted solution to an older question here [Google Maps Marker as a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107410/google-maps-marker-as-a-link)

This is what I've put together but it won't work http://jsfiddle.net/9GrcW/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it works if you change `this[i].url` to `this.url`:

```
for ( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = this.url;
  });
}
```

Comment: yeah sure, I have to wait another 4 mins before it will let me accept the answer. thanks again